# Deep link and animation using Android Navigation component

Tags: android, animation, android-architecture-navigation, fragmenttransaction, android-deep-link

I'm trying to implement a forgot password flow. What I'd like to do is to handle the received email, which contains a link to a forgot password web page, inside the app.

Using the Navigation component I created a deep link, which opens the right fragment (the one with the password field). So I'm able to change the password. Clicking on back, I return to the login screen, which is the start point of my navigation graph.

Everything works as expected, except for the animations. When I create an action between destination, I'm able to assign enter/exit/popenter/popexit animations, but with deep link I don't create any action, so when I push back, I reach the expected fragment but no animation is played.

I tried to play a bit with the code, but no results, and I cannot find any possible solution in the docs.

I tried to create some actions in my navigation graph (there are 4 different options right clicking on a destination:

- to destination (the most common and the one I usually use)
- to self (I don't understand the purpose of this)
- return to sourc (I don't understand the purpose of this)
- global

None of them seems to solve my problem. Ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find in the NavController

```
public void navigate(@NonNull Uri deepLink, @Nullable NavOptions navOptions) {
    navigate(deepLink, navOptions, null);
}
```

In NavOptions set your animations in the same way like in an action:

```
val navOptions =
    NavOptions.Builder()
        .setPopUpTo(
            R.id.nav_graph_main,
            false
        )
        .setEnterAnim(R.anim.slide_in_right)
        .setExitAnim(R.anim.slide_out_left)
        .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.slide_in_left)
        .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.slide_out_right)
        .build()
```